# how fix 'is missing in props validation eslint react/prop-types' error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, vite, react-props

> 'name' is missing in props validation eslint [react/prop-types](https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-react/tree/master/docs/rules/prop-types.md)

> 'description' is missing in props validation eslint [react/prop-types](https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-react/tree/master/docs/rules/prop-types.md)

```
export default function Note({name,description}) {
  return (
    <div>        
        <h1>{name}</h1>
        <p>{description}</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

```
import Note from './Note'

export default function NoteList() {
  return (
    <div>
        <Note name="roze" description="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur" />
        <Note name="sam" description="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur" />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try  **prop-types** package using this command

> `npm install prop-types`

And then for your case you can use this code

```
  // Note.js
  import React from 'react';
  import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

 export default function Note({ name, description }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{name}</h1>
      <p>{description}</p>
    </div>
  );
  }

  Note.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  description: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
 };
```

NoteList.js Leave as is

Answer (score 0):

The code is wanting you to create a type for the props being passed into the `Note` component. You can do so like this:

```
type NoteProps = {
   name: string;
   description: string;
}

export default function Note({name,description}: NoteProps) {
  return (
    <div>        
        <h1>{name}</h1>
        <p>{description}</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: but i didn't use typescript, why this error happen?